# wordpress- in contact form recaptcha not working

Tags: wordpress

I have integrated secret key and site key to the contact form for recaptcha, but still I can not see the recaptcha over there.

In image there is no tag for recaptcha to add it into the form, though i typed it but it is not working.

[image]

Comment: Which plugin are you using

Comment: No plugin, i am doing it with google recaptcha, is it possible?

Comment: If you are not using any plugin then you will need to manually paste the code provided by recaptcha on form and verify captcha on form submit. I would suggest use some plugin instead of doing it manually.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-recaptcha-integration/

Comment: I dont think you will need shortcode, please see its screenshots

Comment: https://ps.w.org/wp-recaptcha-integration/assets/screenshot-3.png?rev=1731167

Comment: Here is the answer https://nerodev.com/how-to-setup-recaptcha-in-contact-form-7/